# Constrained minimization with unbounded objective function

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Consider the following constrained minimization problem

$$
\begin{align}
\text{minimize} && -2 x +1 \\
\text{with respect to} && x \in \mathbb{R} \\
\text{subject to} && x \geq 0
\end{align} \tag{1}
$$

A minimum does not exist, as the objective function decreases unbounded for $x \rightarrow \infty$.

However, I want to show that now using Lagrange multipliers:

$$
\begin{align}
L(x, \lambda) &= f(x) + \lambda g(x) \\
f(x) &= -2x + 1 \\
g(x) &= -x
\end{align}
$$

The partial derivatives of $L$ set to zero give the following equations

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}L(x, \lambda) &= -\lambda - 2 = 0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}L(x, \lambda) &= -x = 0
\end{align}

From this would follow that $x = 0$. But why is here $x = 0$, which is the argument which gives the largest function value?

**Question**: How to derive the correct answer, namely that the objective function has no minimum, using the above approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lagrange multipliers technique furnishes the lagrangian stationary points. After, those points should be qualified. This qualification should indicate if any of the determined stationary points is a minimum point. So you can formulate

$$
L(x,\lambda,s) = -2x+1+\lambda(x-s^2)
$$

Here $s$ is a slack variable needed because the technique only handles equality restrictions.

The stationary points are obtained by solving

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \left\{
\begin{array}{c}
 \lambda -2=0 \\
 x-s^2=0 \\
 \lambda  s=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

giving

$$
x = 0,\ \ \lambda = 2,\ \ s = 0
$$

Here $s=0$ shows us that the restriction is actuating. Analyzing now the restriction gradient which is $1$ and considering that $\min_x f(x) = -2x+1\equiv \max_x -f(x) = 2x-1$ we see that $\nabla( -f(x)) = 2$ so the objective function grows without limit inside the feasible region $(x \ge 0)$ hence the found stationary point cannot be qualified as a minimum point.

Comment: Thanks, one follow up question, if I used the KKT conditions, no additional slack variable would be required, right? I then would get $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x) = \lambda \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x) \Rightarrow \lambda = 2 \geq 0$. Is it then also correct to argue, since $\lambda = 2$ does not impose restrictions on $x$, that $x$ can be chosen arbitrary (as long as it satisfies the constraint $g(x) \leq 0$) and so the no minimum can exist?

Comment: In the answer conclusion I used the KKT criterion without saying so. We should be careful with the adopted conventions regarding the restrictions and minimization/maximization.

Comment: Ok, I take that as a "yes".